# How can I pass a list comprehension results into a csv using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have two lists with variable lengths

```
list1 = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5']

list2 = ['x5','x4']
```

I try the following to find the missing elements

```
*[item for item in list1 if item not in list2], sep='\n'
```

but if I do

```
item = *[item for item in skuslist if item not in retaillist], sep='\n'
csvwriter.writerow(item)
```

I get can't assign to list comprehension

How can I pass the results to writerow?

Comment: I get them in one row like [x1],[x2],[x3]

Comment: The "long" way would be `csvwriter.writerow([item for ...], sep="\n")`. You might be thinking of `csvwriter.writerow(*item)`, but you can't mix positional and keyword arguments in a single tuple like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
import csv

list1 = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5']
list2 = ['x5','x4']

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerow([item for item in list1 if item not in list2])
```

Comment: Is not working again I get in csv ['x1'],['x2'],['x3'].. in one row

Comment: @Evridiki Do you want it newlines ?

Comment: @Evridiki be aware that posting multi-line text in comments doesn't create multi-line text, hence the confusion

Comment: @Evridiki there you go

Comment: remember to close the file with `f.close()` after writing to it.

Comment: the `with` statement will [automatically do that for us](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#context-managers).

Comment: @Evridiki What output are you getting ?

Comment: @kunal ['x1']...row by row as expected but how I send to csv only the values?

Comment: @Evridiki can you try it now

Comment: @kunal no effect if I use for item in list1 if item not in list2 , Its working if I do the opposite! The two lists are coming from two different csv files, first csv for list1 has 1 column second csv for list2 has 6 columns

Comment: @Evridiki -- 'list2 has 6 columns' -- so the list data is being pulled from external files?   If so, all the answers require tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `writerows` to write one item per line, and put each item in a 1-element list:

```
list1 = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5']

list2 = {'x5','x4'}

import csv

with open("test.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    cw = csv.writer(f)
    cw.writerows([x] for x in list1 if x not in list2)
```

Detail: create a `set` for values to exclude, as lookup is faster (that is, for more elements)

Comment: If I do set(list1).difference(list2) I get unhashable type list why?

Comment: not with those examples. That's because either lists contain other lists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to accomplish this task.  This method create a set based on the differences between list1 and list2.  The code also writes the values to the CSV file in order.

```
import csv

list1 = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5']
list2 = ['x5','x4']

# Obtain the differences between list1 and list2
list_difference = (list(set(list1).difference(list2)))

# Uses list comprehension to write the values to a CSV file.
# Uses sorted to write the values in order to the CSV file.
with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
   csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile)
   csv_writer.writerows([[x] for x in sorted(list_difference)])
   outfile.close()
```

You can also do it this way.

```
import csv

list1 = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5']
list2 = ['x5','x4']

# Obtain the differences between list1 and list2.
# Uses list comprehension to write the values to a CSV file.
# Uses sorted to write the values in order to the CSV file.
with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
   csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile)
   csv_writer.writerows([[x] for x in sorted(list(set(list1).difference(list2)))])
   outfile.close()
```